# Internal Action was not loaded Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, agent, multi-agent

I am trying to run an implementation a jason code that is using some Internal Actions. The interpreter is showing that it was not possible to find the "java" code of the internal action, as showed:

```
Server running on http://191.36.8.42:3272
[aslparser] [peleus.asl:29] warning: The internal action class for 'org.soton.peleus.act.plan(Goals)' was not loaded! Error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.soton.peleus.act.plan
[aslparser] [peleus.asl:42] warning: The internal action class for 'org.soton.peleus.act.isTrue(H)' was not loaded! Error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.soton.peleus.act.isTrue
[peleus] Could not finish intention: intention 1:  +des([on(b3,table),on(b2,b3),on(b1,b2)])[source(self)] <- ... org.soton.peleus.act.plan(Goals); !checkGoals(Goals); .print("Goals ",Goals," were satisfied") /
{Goals=[on(b3,table),on(b2,b3),on(b1,b2)]}Trigger: +des([on(b3,table),on(b2,b3),on(b1,b2)])[noenv,code(org.soton.peleus.act.plan([on(b3,table),on(b2,b3),on(b1,b2)])),code_line(29),code_src("peleus.asl"),error(action_failed),error_msg("no environment configured!"),source(self)]
[peleus] Adding belief clear(table)
```

This mas2j file is as following:

```
MAS peleus {
    infrastructure: Centralised
    agents: 
        peleus;            
}
```

Part of agent code (written by Felipe Meneguzzi) is showed bellow:

```
//The next line is line 28
+des(Goals) : true
     <- org.soton.peleus.act.plan(Goals);
         !checkGoals(Goals);
         .print("Goals ",Goals," were satisfied").

+!checkGoals([]) : true <- true.

//The next line is line 40
+!checkGoals([H|T]) : true
    <- .print("Checking ", H);
        org.soton.peleus.act.isTrue(H);
        !checkGoals(T).
```

I guess it is about the folder structure, how to set up Jason to search for java files in specific locations?

The folders structure is like this:

```
 Peleus\src\org\soton\peleus for java files
 Peleus\examples for mas2j and asl tested project
```

Comment: Please do not format stack tracees as blockquotes, use code format so the original indentation is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you are executing the application.

- If you are using java, the CLASSPATH should be defined to include the missing classes.
- if you are using jason script (that uses Ant), the .mas2j file should include the class path as well.

More on that in the [FAQ](http://jason.sourceforge.net/faq/#how-to-set-the-classpath-for-running-a-system). Notice that CLASSPATH is where .class files are found, not .java source code files. The error regards a missing class, not a missing source code.